# Find all elements that has a specified nested child

Tags: xpath

Hey, i've parsed html doc. need to find all element that has a specified child(can be not a direct child).

for ex:

```
<center>
  <table>
    ...
    <a />
</center>
```

find all "center" tags that has nested link
thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, 13 character-long solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//center[.//a]
```

This selects all `center` elements in the document that have an `a` descendent.

And this:

```
//center[.//*/a]
```

selects all `center` elements in the document that have an `a` descendent, which is not a child of this `center` element.

Comment: @Dimitre: Here is the only case where `.//` abbreviated notation has some meaning. I think you have a typo.

Comment: @Alejandro: Good catch, thanks. Fixed. I have been doing many things in parallel lately, so I am unusually absent-minded at times.

Comment: The OP mentions that the specified child, "a", cannot be a direct descendent.

Comment: @ewh: Thanks, I was following just the last sentence of the question. Now I have added one more XPath expression that also handles the request in the beginning of the question.

Comment: I think it say "can be not" instead of "must not be"... `[*//a]` would be shorter.

Comment: @Alejandro: Well, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
//center[element()//a]
```

This says to find all 'center' elements that contain any 'a' elements that
are descendents of 'center's direct element children.

Comment: This is not XPath 1.0 syntax.

Comment: @Alejandro: You are correct.  I normally work with XPath 2.0.  Do not have to mess with XPath 1.0 that often anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the descendant axis in the predicate?

```
//center[descendant::a]
```